# Contact Form missing (send.php file)

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Hi i would just like to ask some help regarding my contact form because I do not know how to create a php script to run on submit my form (send.php). Here my code for the Contact Form:

```
                <div class="contact_form_holder">
                    <form id="contact" class="row" name="form1" method="post" action="#">

                        <div class="span4">
                            <label>Nom</label>
                            <input type="text" class="full" name="name" id="name" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="span4">
                            <label>Email <span class="req">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" class="full" name="email" id="email" />
                            <div id="error_email" class="error">Please check your email</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span8">
                            <label>Message <span class="req">*</span></label>
                            <textarea cols="10" rows="10" name="message" id="message" class="full"></textarea>
                            <div id="error_message" class="error">Please check your message</div>
                            <div id="mail_success" class="success">Thank you. Your message has been sent.</div>
                            <div id="mail_failed" class="error">Error, email not sent</div>

                            <p id="btnsubmit">
                                <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send" class="btn btn-large" /></p>
                        </div>


                    </form>
                </div>
```

Here my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#send").click(function(){
    var name   = $("#name").val();
    var email  = $("#email").val();
    var message  = $("#message").val();

    var error = false;

     if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf("@") == "-1" || email.indexOf(".") == "-1"){
       var error = true;
       $("#error_email").fadeIn(500);
     }else{
       $("#error_email").fadeOut(500);
     }
     if(message.length == 0){
        var error = true;
        $("#error_message").fadeIn(500);
     }else{
        $("#error_message").fadeOut(500);
     }

     if(error == false){
       $("#send").attr({"disabled" : "true", "value" : "Loading..." });

       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "send.php",    
         data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + "You Got Email" + "&message=" + message,
         success: function(data){    
          if(data == 'success'){
            $("#btnsubmit").remove();
            $("#mail_success").fadeIn(500);
          }else{
            $("#mail_failed").html(data).fadeIn(500);
            $("#send").removeAttr("disabled").attr("value", "send");
          }     
         }  
       });  
    }
        return false;                      
  });    
});
```

I'm guessing i need the url : "send.php", Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You could just have the form submit to send.php... Have you looked at tutorials on processing forms with PHP?

Comment: http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/
php mailer- http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebmail

Comment: i do not know much about php that's why im asking for help.. to get this working...

Answer (score 2):

you should give your action page where you are receiving your data. your code could be like this..

```
<form id="contact" class="row" name="form1" method="post" action="send.php">
```

Comment: It is ajax, JS is sending data... see this bit `$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "send.php",    
         data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + "You Got Email" + "&message=" + message,
         success: function(data){  ` If you suggestion is the OP should submit via a form you should show how to process the data on the PHP side.

Comment: yes, i think i should put the action="send.php"...but i don't have the send.php file... with the php code to work my form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all  actually submits the surrounding form.
Use  Because it does nothing next to submit.
Secondly in your ajax call you have written :

```
success: function(data){   
    if(data == 'success'){
        $("#btnsubmit").remove();
        $("#mail_success").fadeIn(500);
    }
});
```

The if condition is invalid if the value of data is not 'success'. I don't know whether it is returning success or not.

So lastly change input type submit to input type button .. hope it will work..

Comment: Hi, thank you....but im afraid im not good at coding... can you help me with the code to make it work???

Answer (score 0):

Make a file name with "send.php" in the same root where it's html file exist.
and some php code here ...

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .

//mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);
mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: I think this could work for me.... I will try it... thank you. I will port the results.